# How to get distinct id in subquery from fact table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to return all the fields in my sub query minus the duplicated childid's in the fact table cor.score. I don't want the duplicate id's to inflate my count. Every id needs to be counted once.

```
select distinct cs.childid
from
(select s.sitename, c.primarylanguage, count(Primarylanguage) as 'Count'
from cor.scores cs
left join cor.sites s on s.id = cs.siteid
left join cor.children c on c.id = cs.childid
group by s.sitename, c.primarylanguage)
```

Error:

> ```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
> ```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Your query makes no sense anyway...

Comment: You're missing a table alias at the end of your query. `...group by s.sitename, c.primarylanguage) t1` But @jarlh is right, your query is very strange. A `distinct` and `group by`?

Comment: `t1` Is just a sample alias, so you'll need to change your  select on the outer query to the appropriate alias. In my case you would change it to `select distinct t1.childid...`

Comment: @Simon except childid isn't a field being returned in the sub-query, so that would need to be sorted as well

Comment: @MatthewHart I didn't see that, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct cs_childid
from
(

select s.sitename,cs.childid as cs_childid, c.primarylanguage, count(Primarylanguage) as 'Count'
from cor.scores cs
left join cor.sites s on s.id = cs.siteid
left join cor.children c on c.id = cs.childid
group by s.sitename, c.primarylanguage,cs.childid

)as T
```

Comment: This query will fail. You have a `group by` and you don't have any aggregation done on `cs.childid`.

Comment: Simon you are right and i changed my query hope this will work

Comment: PJ.SQL can you check this query please

Comment: My logic is clearly poor, and that's my fault,  so let me try to explain again. I want all the fields in my subquery to be returned. However, the fact table (cor.scores) has many duplicated childid's. I don't want duplicated Id's to inflate my count. They need to be counted once. Your query only returns unique ID's.

Comment: can you please put your sample data , that would be helpful to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:
   1. can return any column of subquery

```
    select  s.childid,s.[Count]
    FROM (
        SELECT s.sitename, c.primarylanguage,cs.childid, count(Primarylanguage)OVER(PARTITION BY s.sitename) as 'Count'
        FROM cor.scores cs
        LEFT join cor.sites s on s.id = cs.siteid
    ) AS s LEFT join cor.children c on c.id = s.childid
```

Or this:
   2. Only can return group column and aggregate columns

```
    select  s.childid,s.[Count]
    FROM (
        SELECT s.sitename,cs.childid, count(Primarylanguage)OVER(PARTITION BY s.sitename) as 'Count'
        FROM cor.scores cs
        LEFT join cor.sites s on s.id = cs.siteid
        GROUP BY s.sitename,cs.childid
    ) AS s LEFT join cor.children c on c.id = s.childid
```